# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Moderator election #1](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Hardware Recommendations has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Jeff Schaller]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6545978826948608).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for volunteering your time and energy Jeff!

This Stack Exchange tends to attract quality community members... and moderators!

It's nice to have another moderator with extensive Linux experience/knowledge.  That's always a big plus.